# Is there a way to replace all characters that isn't a certain character with already converting it to underscores

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Right so I am doing a hangman project with html, CSS and JavaScript with jQuery.

What I do is it converts the string to underscores like this

```
var hidden_word;

hidden_word = aWord.replace(/[a-z]/gi, ' _ ');
$("#word").html(hidden_word);
```

and then later if a letter is clicked it should change the appropriate underscore with the correct letter.

This is what I have done with it( It doesn't work since it just converts all of it back )

```
if(aWord.includes(guess)){
    for(var q=0; q<aWord.length; q++){
        if (aWord[q] == guess){ indices.push(q+1); counter++; 
            $("#word").html(aWord.replace(/Q/g, ' Q '));
        }
        
        console.log(counter);
    }
```

I have done some research but couldn't really find anything.

Any ideas, on how to make it so it converts the one that the letters are at?

Comment: How would one do that?

Comment: I think what I need to somehow do is replace all but something. Not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to map letters of `aWord` where `aWord` equals to a string `abc` to an object e.g. `{a: "_", b: "_", c: "_"}`, then you can iterate through that object each type user types something then return its values, before return you  can check if the object has the typed letter by the user, then you can update object's value either setting the current value with same key so when you return again the UI this time will return correct results, let's an example:

```
const aWord = "abcdef"; // generated based on your logic
const mappings = {}; // initial empty object

aWord.split('').forEach((_, i) => mappings[aWord[i]] = '_'); // fill in the object with letters as keys and underscores as values by default

const guess = "f"; // coming from user

if (aWord.includes(guess)){ // if word has guessed letter, we update object
    mappings[guess] = guess;
}

// mappings now will be => {a: "_", b: "_", c: "_", d: "_", e: "_", f: "f"}
console.log(mappings);
```

Comment: I cant seem to get it to work. I have done something wrong I just can't place my finger on what const mappings = {};
`var sd;
aWord.split('').forEach((_, i) => mappings[aWord[sd]] = '_');
for (let sd=0; sd <= aWord.length; sd++) {if (mappings[sd]) {mappings[sd] = aWord[sd]; }}
$("#Q").click(function(){$("#Q").css("visibility", "hidden");guess = "Q";if(aWord.includes(guess)){for(var q=0; q<aWord.length; q++){if (aWord[q] == guess){ indices.push(q+1); counter++; $("#word").html(hidden_word.replace(/Q/g, ' Q '));
}console.log(counter);}`

Comment: @Tortoise41 I refactored my code, hope it's clear now for you

Comment: Perfect is there anyway to show the mappings as HTML e.g. when they get say n correct it shows it where n is on the underscores.

Comment: You can do something like this `Object.values(mappings).join(' ')` which will print mappings as `_ _ _ _ _ f` and each time an occurrence happens, let's say user typed `b` this time, results will be `_ b _ _ _ f` and so on so forth ;) don't forget to mark my answer as correct. cheers